# CORK on Blender fails when using the OFF import plugin

Tags: modifiers, add-on, import

I posted this on another, less expert site a few weeks ago, and while I did get some general advice and I barked up those trees to see if it would work, nothing came of it, not so far. I'll start with what I know and work backwards to what I guess.

I can install the OFF import plugin and CORK on Blender plugin. CoB has no issues installing at all and OFF will install as long as you unzip it first and point it to the off_import.py file. On one machine, I was able to get it running by placing it manually in the addons folder, but both installation paths lead to the same issue. Once installed the OFF import plugin does its job just fine, even with very complex meshes. When I try to use the CORK on Blender boolean plugin, all functions throw this error:

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "usr/lib/blender/2.70/scripts/addons/import_off.py", line 97, in execute mesh = load(self, context, **keywords)
>
> File "usr/lib/blender/2.70/scripts/addons/import_off.py", line 184, in load file =(filepath, 'r')
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/tmp/tmpmq0jcfzc/result.off'
>
> location: /usr/lib/blender/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:189

If there's more, I'm not seeing it.

So it seems like just pointing in the wrong places, but I've barked up that tree to best of my ability for over a week now. I'm asking for help here because it was suggested I contact the developers, but I'm still not sure this isn't user error, and I'd rather not bug devs about an issue that so far seems to effect just one lone idiot.

I've tried this on my main workhorse and did a fresh (including OS) install on my sacrificial computer and it's having the same issues. I'm running Linux Mint Sonya 18.2 MATE 64 bit, latest stable version.
I've installed blender from the ppa, and I'm running version 2.79.
CORK on Blender came from it's github, https://github.com/dfelinto/cork-on-blender. I did not compile the CORK binary, I used the one available on the git, figuring it would be one less place I could introduce error. CoB has the OFF import plugin as a dependency, which I also took from the github. https://github.com/alextsui05/blender-off-addon.

I've banged my head into several corners over the last few weeks and I'd like first to see if it's just me. Is anyone else able to replicate this issue? Is there any other info would be useful in figuring this out?